# Como implementar a camada oculta em uma rede neural de reconhecimento de caracteres?

Tags: aprendizagem-de-máquina, mlp, redes-neurais

Estou estudando redes neurais – mais especificamente redes neurais multilayer perceptron (MLP) – e estou com algumas dúvidas para implementar uma rede dessas para reconhecimento de caracteres.

A dúvida mesmo é de quantas camadas devo implementar (nesse caso acredito que devem ser três: a de entrada, a oculta e a de saída) e como deve ser a implementação da camada oculta:

1. quantos neurônios deve possuir a camada oculta?
2. que tipo de função de ativação devo implementar na camada oculta para que ela seja capaz de passar dados para a camada seguinte (a de saída) que ajudem na tarefa de reconhecimento de caracteres?

De resto já consegui implementar, as dúvidas seriam só nesse aspecto mesmo.

Valeu!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Sobre as Camadas

A sua rede neural precisa ter *no mínimo* as camadas de entrada e de saída, já que a camada de entrada é responsável por receber os valores do problema (os "impulsos") e a camada de saída é responsável por dar a(s) resposta(s) (o valor da regressão ou da classificação).

A(s) camada(s) intermediária(s) (oculta) tem o propósito de capturar/representar as diversas nuances que os dados de treinamento podem ter. Em teoria, quanto mais camadas ocultas você tiver, mais ajustada pode ficar a sua rede. Isto é especialmente útil quando o problema não é linearmente separável, pois há muitas pequenas nuances que diferenciam um determinado dado entre as classes a que ele pode pertencer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De fato, se o problema é linearmente separável você não precisaria de *nenhuma* camada oculta pois as diferenças já podem ser aprendidas só com os neurônios das camadas de entrada e saída - tal qual você mesmo poderia fazer apenas com um ou mais simples IF's no seu código (leia o comecinho [desta minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40135/explicar-o-algoritmo-svr/40149#40149) em uma outra pergunta aqui do SOPT pra entender um pouco mais sobre esse raciocínio).

Se por um lado mais camadas ocultas tornam a rede mais específica às nuances dos dados em problemas não linearmente separáveis, por outro lado elas podem facilitar que o ajuste seja grande demais sobre os dados de treinamento mesmo com poucas interações de treinamento (esse é o tal de [sobreajuste](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobreajuste), em que a rede funciona perfeitamente para os dados de treinamento mas erra para dados de problemas reais). Adicionalmente, mais camadas naturalmente demandam mais processamento, e assim a solução torna-se mais computacionalmente custosa.

Na prática, [há um consenso](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1097) de que apenas 1 camada oculta é o ideal para a maior parte dos problemas:

> Uma questão deste assunto em que há consenso é a diferença de
>   desempenho ao adicionar novas camadas ocultas: as situações em que há
>   um ganho significativo de desempenho para a adição de uma nova camada
>   oculta são raras. Assim, uma única camada oculta é suficiente para a
>   grande maioria dos problemas.
>
> Tradução livre do original em inglês:
>
> *One issue within this subject on which there is a consensus is the performance difference from adding additional hidden layers: the
>   situations in which performance improves with a second (or third,
>   etc.) hidden layer are very small. One hidden layer is sufficient for
>   the large majority of problems.*

### Sobre os Neurônios

Na camada de entrada precisa-se ter um neurônio para cada característica do vetor do problema utilizado (entenda como "para cada coluna da tabela"). Mas isso também depende de como a característica é representada. No caso de valores contínuos (como temperatura medida em graus em ponto flutuante, por exemplo), é usado um único neurônio. Mas se os valores são discretos, usa-se um neurônio para cada valor possível de (0, 1 e 2, por exemplo, para representar temperaturas baixa, média e alta). As vezes também se adiciona um neurônio a mais na camada de entrada para servir como viés (e "mover" as funções de ativamento de forma controlada - mais detalhes [nesta outra questão do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks)).

Na camada de saída o número de neurônios depende do uso da rede. Se a intenção é fazer uma regressão (estimar um valor a partir dos dados de entrada), há apenas um único neurônio. Há também só um neurônio se o uso é para classificação binária (a rede responde se as características de entrada correspondem ou não a uma única classe). Mas se for construido um classificador multi-classes, há um neurônio de saída para cada classe (um neurônio responde 1 se os dados correspondem à classe por ele representada, sendo que os demais respondem 0 nesse caso).

O número de neurônios da camada intermediária (oculta) é outra questão amplamente discutida. Mas há uma regra empírica simples que diz que se deve utilizar o número médio entre os neurônios nas camadas de entrada e saída, pois isso torna a rede suficientemente robusta para a resolução dos problemas (dado que ela só precisa representar nuances em comparação aos dados de entrada, mas tendo em vista as saídas desejadas).

### Sobre as Funções de Ativação

A função de ativação descreve literalmente quando um neurônio deve ou não ser ativado para um dado valor de ativação (chamado de `net` e resultante da soma ponderada das entradas no neurônio). Considere um exemplo hipotético com apenas um neurônio e algumas entradas de dados. Se você usar uma função degrau ou linear, ele vai ser ativado de uma forma muito similar a um IF em seu código, e assim vai servir apenas para problemas linearmente separáveis. Outras funções, que *não são* lineares, como a [Função Logística](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_log%C3%ADstica) e a [Tangente Hiperbólica](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangente_hiperb%C3%B3lica) se tornam mais úteis para problemas não linearmente separáveis justamente pela forma mais "sutil" em que a decisão é tomada sobre valores mais afastados da fronteira de decisão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A decisão sobre qual função utilizar vai depender essencialmente do seu problema. A Função Logística é comumente utilizada porque ela é bem simples e dá conta do recado para a maior parte dos problemas. Eu não tenho muita experiência prática nesse aspecto, mas sei que para redes neurais que usam retropropagação ([backpropagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)) para o treinamento é fundamental que as funções utilizadas sejam diferenciáveis porque o algoritmo utiliza o método de [gradiente descendente](http://mtm.ufsc.br/~azeredo/calculos/3Acalculo/0/modulo2/graddescendente1.html) para o ajuste dos pesos nos neurônios. Então esse também é outro critério importante, nesses casos.

> P.S.: No caso de reconhecimento de caracteres, sugiro [esta
>   leitura](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1203/1203.0876.pdf) e [este exemplo prático em Python](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html) (que usa a fantástica biblioteca [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) de aprendizado de máquina)

Comment: Bem respondido! +

Comment: Obrigado. [Sua resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61254/73) também foi um bom auxílio/complemento à pergunta. :)

Comment: Os exemplos do PS. (nao tinha reparado neles) tambem estão interessantes.

Comment: @LuizVieira Os problemas não linearmente separáveis são resolvidos traçando-se linhas curvas ou diferente linhas retas?

Comment: @DanOver Na prática as camadas fazem um mapeamento dos dados para que em alguma dimensão (maior) o problema se torne linearmente separável. Então, sim, você pode entender que se usa diferentes "linhas retas" para aproximar uma "linha curva". :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu fiz essa pergunta porque costumo ver duas representações para problemas tipo XOR, sendo uma assim (https://goo.gl/xavwps) e outra semelhante a isso (https://goo.gl/6TB4ib).

Comment: @DanOver Entendi. Veja que a primeira imagem indica que você precisaria ter dois classificadores lineares diferentes pra resolver o XOR (o que só ajudaria nesse problema - em outros, talvez vc precisasse ter dezenas ou centenas de classificadores lineares, tornando impraticável!). A segunda diz o que precisa ser feito na verdade. Veja a imagem que eu postei logo após o gráfico do XOR nesta outra postagem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193712/73 Vai te ajudar a entender o que eu quis dizer com mapeamento pra outra dimensão, onde um só classificador linear é suficiente. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Muito boa a postagem, até dei um "up" nela. Luiz, me ajude em uma outra dúvida, quando dizemos que uma rede está aprendendo a jogar um game competindo contra si própria, o que isso quer dizer? Estamos utilizando um algoritmo de RNA baseado em algoritmo genético (algo como redes TWEANNs) e fazendo com que cada indivíduo da população compita contra outro?

Comment: @DanOver Isso quer dizer que ela está sendo treinada a partir de "tentativa e erro": as ações que ela realiza no jogo (seja sozinha ou contra oponentes diversos) são ponderadas em termos do quão bom é seu resultado e esses dados são reutilizados como entrada em mais um passo de treinamento. Se usa GA ou não, vai depender da implementação e da intenção com o treinamento.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69536/discussion-between-luiz-vieira-and-danover).

Answer (score 3):

Na continuação da resposta anerior... (versão minimalista)

Reconhecimento de um caracteres: dada uma imagem raster do caracter  "adivinhar" qual o caracter.

**Entradas**:
   um entrada por cada pixel da imagem do caracter.

Exemplo:
   20*20 inteiros entre 0 e 255

**Saídas**:
   uma saída por cada possivel caracter

exemplo 100 saídas, uma por cada caracter ascii "normal" (não seria má ideia começar com apenas uma meia dúzia de letras e ir alargando...)

**Arquitectura**; junta-lhe mais uma camada intermédia: exemplo igual à camada de entrada, e estás pronto para as primeiras actividades!

Cenas dos próximos episódios: (1) arranja umas matrizes para cada letra e começa a treinar a rede! (2) começar a estudar o assunto mais a sério :)