# Aprendizagem em redes neuronais

Tags: inteligência-artificial, redes-neurais

Como ocorre a aprendizagem em redes neuronais? 
Qual o conceito por detrás?
Que relação tem com "Deep Learning"?

Comment: Pode te interessar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0pm3BrIUFo            
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlhFWT7vAEw

Comment: Não conheço *Deep Learning*, mas essa linha no [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) (em inglês) é intrigante: "Alternativamente, *deep learning* tem sido caracterizada como um *buzzword*, ou um novo nome para redes neurais."

Comment: Relacionado: ["Como implementar a camada oculta em uma rede neural de reconhecimento de caracteres?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61187/215)

Comment: Te recomendo este curso sobre inteligência artificial, cobre toda a introdução: https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs271

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Realmente você deveria comprar um livro sobre o assunto se realmente está interessado. Mas os conceitos básicos (e põe básicos nisto) são os seguintes:

1) Um neurônio possui um certo número de inputs, e apenas um output. O output pode ser visto como uma "Decisão" tomada com base nos inputs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2) O output do neurônio é bem-comportado, ou seja, é um valor numa faixa predeterminada (algo como "entre 0 e +1"), mesmo que os inputs do neurônio sejam de grandeza muito maior.

3) Para calcular o output, o neurônio atribui um "peso" diferente a cada um dos inputs, faz uma soma linear ponderada dos diversos inputs. Os "pesos" de cada input podem ser alterados.

```
output_linear = peso_a . input_a + peso_b . input_b + ...
```

Naturalmente, se um dos inputs for muito grande, mesmo que seu peso seja pequeno ele vai acabar dominando o output.

Os "pesos" armazenados em cada neurônio são a memória do sistema.

4) Para o output ser "bem-comportado" o resultado da soma linear é comprimido por uma função não-linear, como a função sigmóide:

```
output = 1 / (1 + exp(-output_linear))
```

O uso de uma função não-linear no output é um dos aspectos que garante que uma rede neural possa "aprender" qualquer função.

5) Um único neurônio, também chamado de Perceptron, já tem serventia para algumas decisões simples, por exemplo parar o carro ou andar num cruzamento. Um input é o sinal vermelho, o outro pode ser uma ambulância se aproximando (cujo peso deve ser alto porque tem mais prioridade que o sinal vermelho), etc.

Um Perceptron também seria capaz de calcular quanto de sabão a máquina de lavar deve usar em função de algumas variáveis, ou qual o preço de venda de um produto para que ele dê lucro.

6) Uma rede neural mais capaz que o Perceptron tem uma ou mais camadas escondidas, ou seja, grupos de neurônios que não estão ligados nem diretamente ao input, nem ao output, formando uma malha de sinapses (ligações entre neurônios).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma função extremamente simples, como a função XOR (Ou exclusivo), não pode ser aprendida por um Perceptron, mas pode ser aprendida por uma rede neural com camada escondida. Abusando um pouco da metáfora, um Perceptron não aprende funções com características "altruístas".

7) Através do mecanismo de "backpropagation", é possível "treinar" uma rede neural. Para isto, deve haver uma fase de aprendizado, onde os neurônios da rede são submetidos a um certo conjunto de inputs, e calcula-se o erro (diferença entre output observado e esperado). O erro é utilizado para recalcular os pesos da rede neural, de frente para trás (começando pelo neurônio de output e dali em direção aos inputs).

Se os neurônios fazem uso de uma função não-linear para o output, pode ser provado que a rede neural pode "aprender" qualquer função via backpropagation.

O processo de aprendizado e funcionamento da rede neural é essencialmente estatístico, é análogo à lógica difusa. Uma rede neural treinada para reconhecer letras vai responder sempre com um grau de incerteza (em vez de "esta letra é A", o output seria algo como "95% de chance de ser a letra A").

Por último, segue um artigo onde comparo neurônios com agentes econômicos, talvez interesse: https://epxx.co/artigos/economianeural.php

Comment: Na verdade já venho estudado sobre o assunto há algum tempo @epx. Mas em todo caso quis enriquecer mais o site e saber de vós alguma coisa, sobre este assunto que anda um pouco em voga. :D. Thks

Comment: Espero ter contribuído à altura das expectativas.

Answer (score 3):

As redes neurais são um dos mais famosos tipos de algoritmos de aprendizado de máquina e sua ideia principal é basicamente imitar o comportamento do cérebro humano. Se tiver algum conhecimento em programação e estatística, irá entender melhor como funcionam estes algoritmos.

A diferença de uma rede neural para outra é o processo de treinamento. A partir dos exemplos mostrados a ela, a rede neural vai ajustando seus parâmetros de acordo com as respostas. Por exemplo, para treinamento de uma rede neural com o intuito de classificar notícias, devem ser exibidos exemplos de notícias à ela. Ou seja, a rede neural regula as “sinapses” do “cérebro” para classificar novos exemplos automaticamente.

Já Deep Learning é um aprendizado de máquina de âmbito mais profundo, mais amplo e com estruturas mais complexas.

Para maiores informações sobre assunto e alguns conceitos acesse este [link](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/19/machine-learning-e-azure/).

Answer (score 1):

Podemos pensar o aprendizado em redes neurais da mesma forma que pensamos quando queremos entender como os humanos aprendem, darei aqui um exemplo prático, imagine o Michael Jordan treinando para acertar a cesta de 3 de uma grande distância, o que ele faz pra acertar?Ele com certeza vai testar inúmeras vezes.A cada tentativa esta ação terá variáveis de entrada, como por ex:
**Direção à direita, Direção à esquerda, Direção para cima, Controle da respiração, Impulso com os pés, Impulso com as mãos.**
Cada variável que eu listei nós daremos o nome de **X**, e listaremos como **X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6** perceba que listei até 6 (x6), por que é exatamente o número de entradas que eu listei, para **n** entradas **Xn**, e para representar posteriormente a junção das letras usaremos a letra **j**.
Depois de termos as entradas nós vamos adicionar pesos (valor que multiplica a variável, usaremos  **W** que significa seu poder de influência na váriavel **X**), a cada variável, multiplicando-o, ou seja, cada variável será influenciada pelo seu peso, imagine que o Michael Jordan sofreu uma lesão no cérebro e esqueceu tudo sobre basquete, então a primeira tentativa seria bem maluca! Jogaria pra lateral da quadra talvez! Mas a cada tentativa ele iria melhorando, "calibrando", ou seja, a cada nova tentativa os  "pesos" seriam atualizados objetivando um erro cada vez menor para fazer a cesta. Após inúmeras tentativas com certeza o Michael vai diminuir o erro drasticamente e acertar essa cesta. Agora tentemos compreender isso de forma mais matemática.
**Cesta é verdadeira se a soma de Xj.Wj > T, caso o contrário ele não fez a cesta.**

**X**= Entradas 
**j**= Junção somatória, só pra representar na fórmula mesmo. 
**w**= São os pesos 
**T**= É o valor de corte de ativação (limite)

O conceito é um pouco mais complexo que isso mas acho que esse exemplo pode te ajudar a pensar de forma mais abstrata usando um exemplo prático.Já sobre como deeplearning se relaciona com redes neurais é simples, deeplearning tem muito mais camadas, ou seja, é bem mais complexo, nada demais.