# O que é rede neurais na programação?

Tags: terminologia, redes-neurais

Tenho pesquisado muito ultimamente sobre rede neurais na programação e são poucas a referencias sobre rede neurais na programçaõ no brasil. Além disso são pouquissimos exemplos de rede neurais em diferentes linguagens de programação.
Para que serve rede neurais em programação?

Comment: Tenho certeza vai ser fechada...

Comment: Porque fez a pergunta então?!

Comment: As respostas desta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81989/aprendizagem-em-redes-neuronais) responde muito bem a sua dúvida a respeito do que são redes neurais.