# Como classificar dados com uma Rede Neural Perceptron?

Tags: inteligência-artificial, redes-neurais

Criei uma rede neural perceptron para entender bem o conceito. O meu objetivo seria definir o que é uma laranja, por seus números de elementos químicos e o que é uma maçã pela mesma formula. É uma rede neural de apenas **uma camada**, eu teria que utilizar uma rede de **multi-camadas** para realizar este processo? Alguém poderia mostrar um exemplo prático? Seria bacana falarmos um pouco sobre.

Comment: Seria ótimo se alguém disponibilizasse um exemplo algoritmo em prática aplicando esse conceito de IA MLP, ainda mais porque semestre que vem irei fazer um TCC sobre exatamente isso rs.

Comment: @PauloRoberto verdade! Entendi o conceito e coloquei em prática, mas existem muitas dúvidas ainda como utilizar este tipo de RN.

Comment: tem essa resposta aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82061/3082 pra dar uma aprofundada na situação se vc se interessar

Comment: Pois é mas quero falar especificamente de Perceptron o pessoal não entende. Quero saber o que é possível fazer e o que não é? Como o exemplo que passei...

Comment: O perceptron é um classificar binário linear. Dá pra resolver qualquer problema com este algoritmo, desde que os conjuntos de dados possam ser classificados em dois (ou seja, laranjas e maçãs, por exemplo) e linearmente separáveis (se os dados estiverem em R^n, existe um hiperplano em R^(n-1) que divide os dois grupos). É esta a resposta procurada?

Comment: O colega @Marcus têm toda razão. Ou seja, dá pra usar um único perceptron pra resolver o problema das laranjas vs maçãs se esses "dados" (representados por "elementos químicos" - seja lá o que vc quis dizer aqui) forem linearmente separáveis. Se vc quer exemplos práticos, dá uma olhada aqui: http://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-perceptron-algorithm-scratch-python/

Comment: @LuizVieira penso em passar por exemplo a acidez das frutas como exemplo.

Comment: Ok. Então faz assim: meça a acidez de algumas frutas (tanto de laranjas como de maçãs) e plote num gráfico (pode ser um histograma mesmo, com a contagem do número de frutas de cada tipo por valor de acidez). Se com essa única característica o problema for linearmente separável vai ficar bem visível no gráfico (como no clássico problema dos peixes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40135/explicar-o-algoritmo-svr/40149#40149).

Comment: Interessante! @LuizVieira