# Como funciona uma rede neural artificial?

Tags: algoritmo, inteligência-artificial, aprendizagem-de-máquina, redes-neurais

Sei que essa pergunta é bastante corriqueira e é fácil encontrar a resposta, porém, eu gostaria de uma resposta funcional, eu já vi bastante coisa sobre, mas nada entra na minha *cachola*, gostaria de algo mais prático, algo que realmente faça sentido.

Sempre que busco estudar sobre me deparo com um monte de fórmulas doidas e explicações superficiais.

Poderiam por favor me explicar como implementar isto na prática, ou pelo menos um link com um exemplo funcional, sem aquele monte de fórmulas doidas, que sei que é necessário, mas que não ajuda muito de início.

Quero uma explicação simples de como funciona na prática e não esse monte de "O neurônio x faz isso, o evento de ativação..." de onde vem o neurônio? Como implementar? O que é esse tal evento de ativação? Onde são guardados os dados obtido? Tem um banco de dados especial?

Isso que eu não consigo entender, parece que já começam explicando do final.

Comment: Eu provavelmente tenho um exemplo em meu caderno da faculdade, mas não estou com ele aqui agora, vou tentar no final da tarde, e volto aqui

Comment: Ok @WeslleyRocha, fico no aguardo

Comment: 2022 - Depois de tantos anos, apareceu por acaso, pra mim, esse vídeo que explica exatamente sobre uma de minhas dúvidas - "Tem um banco de dados especial?" : https://youtu.be/piF6D6CQxUw

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Breve Revisão

Você deve se lembrar das aulas de álgebra e geometria do colégio onde estudou sobre funções lineares (em que as variáveis - `x`, principalmente - estão sempre no primeiro grau) e também sobre a [Equação Reduzida da Reta](https://www.geogebra.org/m/MH5e3JY4):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na equação reduzida da reta (que obviamente é linear) `x` é chamado de variável independente, `y` (ou `f(x)`) é chamado de variável dependente, e o par `(x,y)` é um ponto no plano cartesiano. Além disso, `m` é o coeficiente angular e indica a inclinação da reta (tal que `m = tan(x)`, ou seja, é a tangente do ângulo entre a reta e o eixo-x), e `c` é o coeficiente linear e indica o ponto onde a reta corta o eixo-y. A imagem a seguir ilustra algumas retas e as suas respectivas equações (observe que quando `x=0` a reta é totalmente horizontal; uma reta totalmente vertical teria `x` tendendo ao infinito, e não é representada dessa forma).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Classificadores Binários

Por que essa revisão? Porque esse conceito é a base matemática para os [Classificadores Binários](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification), dentre os quais as Redes Neurais também se encontram.

> **Observação**: Os problemas em Aprendizagem de Máquina envolvem não
>   apenas Classificação, mas também [Regressão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress%C3%A3o_linear) e [Agrupamento
>   (*Clustering*)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering). E mais: ainda podem ser subdivididos de acordo com
>   a forma em que os dados são manipulados para a extração de
>   conhecimento, o que é chamado de [aprendizado supervisionado (com
>   treinamento) e não supervisionado (sem treinamento)](http://prorum.com/index.php/1673/diferenca-algoritmos-aprendizado-supervisionado-supervisionado). Eu escolhi focar
>   em classificação supervisionada porque acho que o entendimento é mais
>   fácil, embora *ainda assim* o assunto seja vasto. Mas lembre-se que as
>   Redes Neurais também são usadas para Regressão, e também são usadas de
>   forma não-supervisionada, e pra um entendimento mais profundo você vai precisar estudar muito mais. :)

Um classificador binário é um modelo que é construído a partir de um conjunto de dados de exemplos rotulados como pertencentes a uma de duas classes possíveis (isto é, trata-se de um aprendizado supervisionado) para que seja capaz de prever a classe a qual pertence um novo exemplo ainda não visto. O uso prático disso pode ser em qualquer tipo de problema que possa ser representado de forma *binária*: separação de laranjas boas ou ruins, tomada de decisão sobre vender ou comprar uma ação, decisão sobre ter ou não um gato em uma imagem, etc.

Na literatura a formalização dos dados de entrada geralmente usa a seguinte notação:

- `X` (maiúsculo) representa uma matriz com `m` exemplos (*samples*) dos dados do problema. Essa matriz tem o formato `m x n`, porque cada exemplo `x` (minúsculo) tem `n` características (*features*) que são usadas para representá-lo (por isso cada exemplo `x` é chamado de *feature vector* na literatura). Por exemplo (totalmente fictício - eu não sei se essas são mesmo as melhores características para esse problema), um sistema de separação de laranjas poderia usar `n=4` características: (1) a intensidade média da cor da casca, (2) o peso da fruta em gramas, (3) uma indicação booleana (0 ou 1) sobre ter ou não ainda um pedaço de galho anexado à fruta, e (4) uma indicação booleana sobre ter ou não rasgos na casca. Como se pode perceber, essas características são numéricas. Se for necessário usar categorias discretas (nome de cor, por exemplo), os valores precisam ser convertidas para números (é comum usar um processo chamado [*one-hot encoding*](https://www.quora.com/What-is-one-hot-encoding-and-when-is-it-used-in-data-science) para isso). Também se pode perceber que as unidades não são as mesmas (as vezes é em gramas, outras em contagem, outras vezes é em litros, etc). Isso significa que os valores também estão nas mais diversas escalas. Porém, para a rede neural, números são números (ela não é capaz de "raciocinar" sobre o seu significado - isso é uma tarefa do projetista). Por isso, para evitar que uma característica se sobressaia a outra, os valores são comumente [normalizados](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/whats-the-difference-between-normalization-and-standardization) para um mesmo intervalo (por exemplo, para valores `float` entre 0 e 1).
- `Y` (também maiúsculo) representa um vetor com os rótulos (*labels*) das classes a qual pertencem *cada* exemplo `x` em `X`. Nas Redes Neurais esses rótulos são 0 para representar a classe A ou 1 para representar a classe B. Em outros modelos usam-se outras representações. Por exemplo, as [Máquinas de Vetores de Suporte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40135/explicar-o-algoritmo-svr), outro modelo bem famoso atualmente, usa -1 para representar a classe A e 1 para representar a classe B. A escolha decorre da implementação do treinamento.

Imagine então que você tem um problema em que os exemplos são representados por duas características `x1` e `x2` (ou seja, `n=2`). Apenas para ilustrar, vou usar o clássico exemplo do operador lógico "E" (*AND*), em que os valores dos bits são considerados como as características e os rótulos são o resultado do *AND* entre os bits:

```
╔════╦════╦═══╗
║ x1 ║ x2 ║ Y ║
╠════╬════╬═══╣
║  0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║
║  1 ║  0 ║ 0 ║
║  0 ║  1 ║ 0 ║
║  1 ║  1 ║ 1 ║
╚════╩════╩═══╝
```

Quando esses dados são plotados em um gráfico (usando `x1` no eixo x e `x2` no eixo y, e o rótulo em `Y` como a classe A ou B) temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deve ser possível perceber que as duas classes são bem separadas espacialmente, de forma que é possível encontrar e traçar uma reta que as separe a partir desses pontos (então chamados de "treinamento" justamente porque serão utilizados para encontrar a tal reta). Com essa reta construída, é possível "prever" se um novo ponto pertence à classe A ou à classe B facilmente, bastando para isso verificar em qual lado da reta ele está.

> Na verdade há infinitas retas possíveis que podem se traçadas entre os
>   três pontos azuis da classe A e o único ponto verde da classe B,
>   dependendo das escolhas dos seus parâmetros de inclinação e corte do
>   eixo y. O Perceptron, que eu ainda vou explicar, encontra uma delas
>   que não é necessariamente a melhor. As Máquinas de Vetores de Suporte
>   têm sido mais populares nesse tipo de problema justamente porque
>   encontram *a melhor* reta: aquela que maximiza as distâncias dos
>   pontos de ambas as classes. Para mais detalhes, leia [esta outra
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40149/73).

### O Neurônio Básico: Perceptron

E como se encontra essa reta? Bom, pra começar ela só é uma reta porque o exemplo ilustrado tinha 2 características - o que significa um gráfico de duas dimensões. Se tivesse 3 características, o gráfico teria três dimensões e a "reta" seria na verdade um plano separando os pontos das duas classes no espaço tridimensional. Por isso, essa fronteira de decisão (outro termo muito comum) é um [hiperplano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiperplano). A equação do hiperplano muda um pouco da equação reduzida da reta, mas não muito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `m` agora é chamado de `w`, pois é o vetor normal (perpendicular) ao hiperplano, mas que ainda serve para caracterizar sua inclinação. O `c` agora é chamado de `b`, pois além de descrever o deslocamento do hiperplano (o ponto de corte dos eixos) ele também representa o enviesamento (viés ou *bias* em inglês) do seu treinamento: isto é, o hiperplano pode estar mais pra um lado ou mais pra um outro dependendo de quantos exemplos vc usou de cada classe. O `x` ainda é a variável independente, mas antes era um valor só e agora é um vetor (o vetor de características de um exemplo). O ponto em `w . x` é o [produto escalar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_escalar) entre os dois vetores (que simplesmente computa uma soma com pesos, isto é, pra cada índice dos vetores - que precisam ter o mesmo comprimento - multiplica os valores em `w` e `x` e soma os resultados). A figura abaixo ilustra a geometria envolvida, para um problema com duas características (`n=2`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, a ideia do treinamento de um modelo classificador é encontrar, a partir dos dados de exemplos que você tem, os valores de `w` e de `b` que representem um hiperplano qualquer que separe os dados nas duas classes. A decisão sobre a classe usa a equação do hiperplano de forma que se `w . x + b > 0`, para um novo `x` não utilizado no treinamento, ele decide que a classe de `x` é a classe A, pois o ponto está "acima" do hiperplano. Se, ao contrário, `w . x + b < 0`, então a classe de `x` é a B pois o ponto está "abaixo" do hiperplano. Observe que qualquer ponto `x` em que `w . x + b = 0` está exatamente sobre o hiperplano, e não é possível decidir qual é a sua classe (se isso ocorrer, é provável que o classificador foi treinado com dados insuficientes).

O [Perceptron](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) é um dos modelos mais simples que faz isso, tendo servido como base para as redes neurais. Esse algoritmo inicia com pesos e viés arbitrários e simplesmente itera sobre os dados disponíveis tentando "prever" a classe. Então ele calcula o erro da previsão com base na saída esperada (que é o rótulo correto esperado para a classe), e ajusta os pesos e o viés proporcionalmente ao erro. Esse processo é repetido para todos os dados de treinamento até que o erro seja 0 (ou seja, o classificador acerte a previsão para todos os dados de treinamento).

Você pode considerar o Perceptron como um único neurônio, com a seguinte arquitetura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os valores `x1`, `x2`, ..., `xn` são as características de um exemplo (de treinamento, durante a construção do modelo, ou de um novo exemplo para o qual vai se tentar prever a classe). Os valores `w1`, `w2`, ..., `wn` são os chamados pesos (*weights*) do neurônio. Lembre-se que juntos eles formam o vetor `w`, que é o vetor normal (perpendicular) ao hiperplano da fronteira de decisão. Para facilitar e permitir que também seja aprendido, é comum adicionar o viés (o valor de `b`) ao final do vetor de pesos (isto é, ele passa a ser o valor `wn+1`), mas para isso é necessário adicionar o valor fixo `1` também ao final do vetor `x` (já que eles precisam ter o mesmo comprimento para o produto escalar).

No modelo do neurônio, o símbolo do somatório representa a soma dos valores de `x` ponderados por `w`, ou seja, o produto escalar. A função `F` é a tal função de ativação. Basicamente o que ela faz é converter o resultado da soma em um valor no intervalo [0, 1] e fazer uma verificação para "ativar" ou não o neurônio. Isso significa essencialmente converter o valor da soma (chamado de `net` na literatura) para o intervalo [0, 1], e gerar o valor 1 somente se o neurônio for ativado. No caso do Perceptron, como se está trabalhando com problemas linearmente separáveis, a função usada também é linear. É comum usar a função [Heaviside (também chamada de função degrau)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Heaviside), pois ela simplesmente devolve 0 ou 1 dependendo do sinal do valor resultante (*net*).

### Código de Exemplo

O código abaixo ilustra uma implementação simples do Perceptron, em Python. Ele depende dos pacotes [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) e [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/) para os gráficos, do pacote [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) para leitura dos dados do banco de dados das flores de Íris, e [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) apenas para ajudar na plotagem do hiperplano de decisão.

```py
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import csv
import numpy as np

# ==============================================================================
def getIrisData():
    X = []
    Y = []
    with open('iris.csv', 'r') as r:
        reader = csv.DictReader(r, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            x = [float(row['Sepal.Length']), float(row['Petal.Length'])]
            if row['Species'] == 'setosa':
                y = 1
            else:
                y = 0
            X.append(x)
            Y.append(y)
    return X, Y, 'Flor de Íris'

# ==============================================================================
def getANDData():
    X = [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1] ]
    Y = [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
    return X, Y, 'Operador E'

# ==============================================================================
def getORData():
    X = [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1] ]
    Y = [ 0, 1, 1, 1 ]
    return X, Y, 'Operador OU'

# ==============================================================================
def main(args):

    # Obtém os dados para teste (escolha um método!)
    #X, Y, probName = getANDData()
    #X, Y, probName = getORData()
    X, Y, probName = getIrisData()

    # Cria o Perceptron de 2 características
    clf = Perceptron(2)

    # Treina o Perceptron
    clf.fit(X, Y)

    # Plota os dados
    pal = sns.color_palette('colorblind', 3)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    X = np.array(X)
    xmin = min(X[:,0]) - 0.5
    xmax = max(X[:,0]) + 0.5
    ymin = min(X[:,1]) - 0.5
    ymax = max(X[:,1]) + 0.5
    ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
    ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])

    ax.set_title('Problema: {}'.format(probName), fontsize=20)
    ax.set_xlabel('$x_1$', fontsize=20)
    h = ax.set_ylabel('$x_2$', fontsize=20, labelpad=20)
    h.set_rotation(0)

    # Plota os pontos de cada classe
    lgClass0 = None
    lgClass1 = None
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        if y == 0:
            color = pal[0]
        else:
            color = pal[1]
        obj, = ax.plot([x[0]], [x[1]], c=color, marker='o', markersize=8,
                                       linestyle='None')
        if y == 0:
            lgClass0 = obj
        else:
            lgClass1 = obj

    # Plota a fronteira de separação (isto é, o hiperplano definido pelos pesos)
    # Para isso, usa uma grade de valores previstos com o próprio classificador
    # treinado a partir dos dados

    h = 0.005 # Tamanho dos "passos" para a grade a ser criada
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xmin, xmax, h), np.arange(ymin, ymax, h))

    Z = []
    for x in np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]:
        Z.append(clf.predict(x.tolist()))

    Z = np.array(Z).reshape(xx.shape)
    CS = ax.contour(xx, yy, Z, colors=[pal[2]])
    #ax.axis('off')

    label = 'Hiperplano separador ($w = [{:.2f}, {:.2f}]$, $b = {:.2f}$)'
    ax.legend([lgClass0, lgClass1, CS.collections[0]],
            ['Classe A', 'Classe B', label.format(clf.w[0], clf.w[1], clf.w[2])],
            ncol=3, loc='upper right', prop={'size': 12})

    plt.show()

# ==============================================================================
class Perceptron:
    '''
    Classe que implementa o classificador linear Perceptron.
    '''

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, n):
        '''
        Construtor da classe.

        Parâmetros
        ----------
        n: int
            Número de características do problema.
        '''
        # Inicializa a lista de pesos
        self.w = [0 for _ in range(n+1)]

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def heaviside(self, net):
        '''
        Função de ativação degrau (heavside).
        Sobre: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Heaviside)

        Parâmetros
        ----------
        net: double
            Valor "líquido" para verificação de ativação.

        Retornos
        --------
        act: int
            Valor de ativação: 0 se não ativado, 1 se ativado.
        '''
        if net > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def predict(self, x):
        '''
        Faz a previsão da classe do exemplo x.

        Parâmetros
        ----------
        x: list
            Vetor de características de um exemplo a ser classificado.

        Retornos:
        class: int
            Classe a qual o exemplo x pertence: 0 indica a classe A, 1 indica a
            classe B.
        '''

        # Adiciona o viés ao final
        x_ = x.copy()
        x_.append(1)

        # Calcula o produto escalar entre os vetores de pesos (w) e entrada (x)
        net = 1
        for i in range(len(self.w)):
            net += self.w[i] * x_[i]

        # Executa a função de ativação
        f = self.heaviside(net)

        # Ativa ou não o neurônio dependendo do resultado da função de ativação
        if f > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def fit(self, X, Y):
        '''
        Treina o Perceptron com base nos exemplos e classes de treinamento
        dados.

        Parâmetros
        ----------
        X: list
            Vetor de exemplos, em que cada exemplo x é um vetor de
            características. Ou seja, é uma lista de listas.
        Y: list
            Vetor de inteiros com as classes verdadeiras (definidas como 0 ou 1)
            às quais os respectivos exemplos em X pertencem.
        '''

        while True:

            adjusted = False

            # Processa cada exemplo
            for x, y in zip(X, Y):

                # Faz a predição da classe do exemplo atual
                y_pred = self.predict(x)

                # Se o Perceptron errou, ajusta os pesos proporcionalmente ao
                # erro obtido
                if y != y_pred:

                    # Adiciona o viés ao final
                    x_ = x.copy()
                    x_.append(1)

                    # Ajusta os pesos
                    for i in range(len(self.w)):
                        self.w[i] += (y - y_pred) * x_[i]
                    adjusted = True

            # Verifica se convergiu (se não houve ajuste, os pesos já estão
            # corretamente ajustados aos exemplos de treinamento). Nesse
            # caso, o treinamento acabou! :)
            if not adjusted:
                break

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# namespace verification for invoking main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Um único neurônio está implementado na classe Perceptron. O método `fit` (nome tradicionalmente utilizado para esse método nas implementações) recebe os valores de `X` (os exemplos) e de `Y` (os rótulos) e os utiliza para o treinamento, fazendo o ajuste dos pesos até que a previsão acerte para todos os exemplos. Depois de treinado, basta usar o método `predict` (nome também tradicionalmente utilizado nas implementações) para que o classificador estime a classe de um novo exemplo `x` qualquer.

A plotagem do hiperplano de separação usa intencionalmente o próprio classificador treinado com os dados, chamando esse método `predict`. Basicamente eu construo uma "grade fina" que pega todo o gráfico, e chamo o classificador pra prever em que lado cada ponto da grade está. A variável `h` define o espaçamento entre os pontos da grade, é tem valor bem pequeno porque eu quero que a fronteira seja a mais próxima possível de uma reta (se vc usar um valor maior ele roda mais rápido porque faz menos predições, mas o contorno de separação no gráfico fica serrilhado).

No exemplo do operador E lógico, o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A linha vermelha/laranja parece passar exatamente sobre um dos pontos, mas na verdade ela está um pouco além dele (ficou bem próxima e por isso é confuso na plotagem). O fato é que o processo de treinamento encontrou a primeira linha que separava os dois grupos de dados (um de cada classe). Lembre-se que ela não é necessariamente a melhor linha separadora, mas serve nesse exemplo.

Se você testar com outros problemas, como o caso do banco de dados clássico de [Flores de Íris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) (usando somente os comprimentos das pétalas e sépalas para ter duas características apenas, e a classe "Setosa" como classe B e as outras duas classes como classe A para ter um problema binário), o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

P.S.: Eu usei o arquivo CSV desse banco de dados disponível [neste link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/datasets/iris.csv).

### E a tal "Rede" Neural?

Como se pode perceber, o Perceptron é basicamente um só neurônio. Acontece que ele não serve pra resolver problemas que não são linearmente separáveis (e, no mundo real, a maioria dos problemas infelizmente não são assim tão fáceis rs). Lembra do problema do E lógico? O problema do OU também é linearmente separável. Mas olha só o problema do Ou-Exclusivo:

```
╔════╦════╦═══╗
║ x1 ║ x2 ║ Y ║
╠════╬════╬═══╣
║  0 ║  0 ║ 0 ║
║  1 ║  0 ║ 1 ║
║  0 ║  1 ║ 1 ║
║  1 ║  1 ║ 0 ║
╚════╩════╩═══╝
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode-se perceber que não dá pra usar uma linha (nesse caso bidimensional) para separar os agrupamentos porque eles não se encontram todos "no mesmo lado". A solução pra isso envolve fazer uma espécie de mapeamento para uma dimensão maior de forma que os dados nessa nova dimensão sejam linearmente separáveis. Fazendo uma ilustração, seria como se os dados bidimensionais fossem distribuídos na superfície de uma esfera (agora com uma dimensão a mais), para que fosse possível separá-los com um plano:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E é aí que entra o [Multilayer Perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron). O princípio é o mesmo de antes, mas agora você tem mais de uma camada (uma "rede" de neurônios), cada uma com seus próprios pesos. A camada de entrada recebe os valores do exemplo `x`, e sua ativação serve de entrada para a camada seguinte, e assim sucessivamente até a última camada (de saída). Como o problema não é mais linear, a função de ativação também não pode ser linear, mas ainda precisa devolver um valor entre 0 e 1. E mais, ela precisa ser *facilmente* derivável, pois o algoritmo de ajuste com base nos erros (o tal do [Backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)) usa um método chamado [Gradiente Descendente](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_do_gradiente)) ao invés de uma mera diferença para ajustar os pesos da última para a primeira camada. Por isso é muito utilizada a [função Sigmóide](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_sigm%C3%B3ide) como função de ativação. Essa função tem a ótima vantagem de que uma vez tendo o seu resultado `net`, o valor de sua derivada pode ser obtido diretamente dele fazendo `net * (1-net)`. Isso é computacionalmente muito eficiente e, portanto, altamente desejável. :)

Mais detalhes do que isso foge do escopo deste site, mas eu acho que a resposta já te dá um bom caminho para aprofundamento nos seus estudos. Os outros usos, para regressão, e até mesmo as [redes convolutivas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rede_neural_convolucional) não deixam de ser especializações desse conceito mais geral. Um bom tutorial de MLP (Multilayer Perceptron) você encontra [neste link](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/), e uma ótima implementação em Python é a do [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html). Eu sugiro também ler [a minha resposta sobre SVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40149/73) aqui mesmo no SOPT. Tem boas informações complementares lá. E sobre a quantidade de camadas, [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61187/73) aqui do SOPT tem mais detalhes.

Caso você esteja se perguntando como funciona no caso de se ter mais do que duas classes, a abordagem comum é simplesmente ter [mais de um classificador treinado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification). Uma forma se chama One-Against-Rest (um contra o resto), em que se faz o que eu fiz nesse exemplo da flor de Íris: se treina um classificador para cada classe de interesse, considerando as demais classes como "a outra". O resultado final (a decisão sobre qual é a classe) é balanceada com base nas distâncias aos respectivos hiperplanos (a maior distância indica a classe mais provável). Mas há também a forma One-Against-One, em que se treina um classificador para cada par de classes. Essa forma é menos usada porque é muito mais computacionalmente custosa.

Comment: Achei excelente começar pelo perceptron! Pelo que vejo por aí nos cursos de machine learning, é muito comum os instrutores pularem esta parte, indo direto pra assuntos mais sofisticados. Eu acho fundamental entender como o perceptron funciona para, a partir dele, extrapolar suas ideias para outros algoritmos na área.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Valeu pelo comentário. Eu concordo contigo. Mas acho que muitos desses cursos são voltados ao uso e não ao entendimento. Isto é, apenas ensinam a programar uma rede usando recursos prontos (do Tensor Flow, por exemplo). Enfim, talvez estamos chegando (já chegamos?) em um ponto em que muita gente não precisa mesmo saber como funciona pra usar. :)

Comment: Além da função sigmóide, usa-se também a função logística e a função tangente. Qual é a vantagem da sigmóide sobre essas outras?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu estou longe de ser especialista em Redes Neurais, mas até onde eu entendo a função logística e a sigmóide são exatamente a mesma (pelo menos do ponto de vista de uso nas RNEs). A sua ideia é mimetizar a ativação de neurônios de forma similar à biológica (ficando próximo do 0 e gradualmente aumentando em direção à 1 conforme aumenta a intensidade da resposta neuronal). Ela é, portanto, similar a tangente hiperbólica nesse sentido. Porém, no caso da sigmóide, a facilidade e a diferenciação eficiente (eu editei a resposta para adicionar um detalhe importante).

Comment: Muito obrigado @LuizVieira, muito bem explicado e finalmente esclareceu pra mim como as coisas funcionam e deu um rumo para meus estudos, de longe a melhor resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Qualquer assunto que trate de Inteligência Artificial vai envolver o mínimo de compreensão matemática e leitura de fórmulas.

Fazendo uma explicação por cima (bem por cima), rede neural quer simular o comportamento de neurônios, ou seja o "conhecimento" é estabelecido pela conexão de diversos neurônios (na programação, funções ou métodos). Cada função deve esperar entradas, e ter uma condição "sináptica" (basicamente uma condição que deve ser atendida para que a função retorne um resultado), a saída dessa função pode/deve ser entrada para uma outra função.

O objetivo básico dessa estrutura é "basicamente" organizar as informações delegando partes do problema para cada função para que o algoritmo seja capaz de adquirir novos conhecimentos através das iterações baseado em reforços.

Existem algoritmos para a implementação da aprendizagem, por exemplo o K-NN. O método de aprendizagem muda de algoritmo para algoritmo e a escolha do mesmo deve ser baseado no problema que você quer resolver.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Isto, como disse na pergunta, eu já sei.. Não entendo, mas já li muito sobre. Me considero até bastante compreendedor dos dois assuntos mínimos que vc citou como pre-requisitos, mas eu quero saber como eles funcionam na prática. Um código que eu consiga testar e dizer "Olha que legal, assim que funciona", não apenas palavras bonitas.

Comment: Compreensível. A meu ver existem pelo menos dois caminhos viáveis para realizar os testes desejados.
1- Você pegar o conceito e as formulas e criar sua própria implementação para exemplos toy para compreensão da aplicação. Alternativamente pode procurar códigos desse tipo no github, pois existem vários.

2 -  usar bibliotecas que implementam o algoritmo como TensorFlow. No próprio site do tensorflow existe uma interface gráfica que permite brincarmos com os conceitos de machine learning.