# O que define uma Rede Neural como sendo Perceptron?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, inteligência-artificial

Acho importante falarmos sobre inteligência artificial, pesquisei aqui no stack**overflow** e não encontrei nada relevante a respeito. Alguém com experiência poderia explicar bem a definição de uma Rede Neural do tipo Perceptron? Sabemos que existem varios tipos de Redes neurais como por exemplo: **Redes ARTs**, **Rede Hopfield**, **Memória associativa**, entre outros. Mas a questão aqui é saber o que diferencia uma rede **Perceptron** das demais?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como funciona uma rede neural artificial?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192098/como-funciona-uma-rede-neural-artificial)

Comment: @diegofm Não é uma duplicata, estou sendo bem especifico aqui amigo, Rede Neural Perceptron e não Redes Neurais no Geral. Pesquisa sobre este tipo de RN, as pessoas não encontram, tentei ontem e não achei nada sobre..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O perceptron é um neurônio de processamento sozinho e solitário, com aprendizado supervisionado. Ele recebe impulsos de vários estímulos, então aplica os pesos relativos de suas sinapses e, então, emite um sinal de saída.

Uma rede de perceptron é um conjunto de vários perceptrons lado a lado, todos recebendo os mesmos estímulos. Como um perceptron não interfere no resultado de outro perceptron, eles podem ser entendidos individualmente sem haver prejuízo do todo.

> Não confundir com Perceptron Multi Camada, MLP da sigla em inglês, em que os perceptrons estão em camada.

O neurônio perceptron aprende com base em seus erros. Sim, literalmente. E depende do tamanho do erro: quanto maior o erro, mais rápido o perceptron tenta se corrigir.

A saída de um perceptron é uma função real que recebe um número real. Os estímulos são transformados em um único número real através de um produto escalar da força dos estímulos com o peso das sinapses. Em resumo, para `X` sendo o estímulo, `p` o resultado do processamento do perceptron, `S` os pesos de suas sinapses e `f` a função real do perceptron:

```
p = f(y)
y = X . S
```

Eu mencionei acima que o perceptron tem aprendizado supervisionado, ele não é autossuficiente como as redes de Kohonen. O aprendizado supervisionado significa aqui que, para cada entrada `T_i` de treinamento, existe um resultado esperado `r_i`. Se `p_i != r_i`, isso significa que houve um erro não nulo, chamado de `e_i`.

Sobre o `e_i` obtido para a entrada `T_i`, corrigem-se os valores das sinapses `S` de tal modo que esse erro terá sido corrigido ou minimizado nesse turno de aprendizado.

A criação do conjunto de aprendizado e de como serão apresentados os elementos de teste pode variar muito dependendo de quem implementa. Normalmente se apresenta o conjunto de testes sequencialmente sucessivas vezes até que um critério de convergência é atingido. O critério de convergência pode ser o erro acumulado total do conjunto de testes. Outro ponto interessante no treinamento é que a taxa de aprendizado normalmente é reduzido entre uma bateria e outra.

Answer (score 3):

O Perceptron é o ancião de todas as redes neurais. O Perceptron é o mais simples tipo de rede neural diretas (Feedfoward), conhecido como classificador linear. Isto significa que os tipos de problemas solucionados por esta rede neural devem ser linearmente separáveis