# Reconhecimento de padrões

Tags: python, r, matlab, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Tenho centenas de imagens digitais de cães e gatos, preciso fazer um algoritmo para reconhecer quando é o cão e quando é o gato. Quais os passos que devo tomar?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo(a) ao SOPT. A sua pergunta tem vários problemas. Primeiramente, ela é muito ampla. Este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Em segundo lugar, você não deixa claro qual é a sua dificuldade principal nesse processo todo. Finalmente, você usou tags de três linguagens diferentes (Python, R e Matlab), mas você deveria escolher uma para obter ajuda mais concreta.

Answer (score 14):

Primeiramente, é legal dizer que esse é um problema famoso de machine-learning. Ele está disponível como [desafio do Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/), de onde também é possível baixar o banco de dados. Inclusive, é de lá que eu baixei os dados para escrever a resposta.

Vou mostrar uma metodologia bem simples para treinar um classificador para esse problema. A resposta é bem um *hello world* desse mundo, mas pode ajudar. [Este artigo](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~pgolle/papers/dogcat.pdf) descreve uma metodologia bem mais avançada para a previsão (o acerto fica em 82% das imagens)

Note também que essa é uma solução em `R` para este problema.

## Ler as imagens para o software

No R você pode ler as imagens usando o pacote `imager`.

```
library(imager)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
img <- imager::load.image("train/cat.0.jpg")
```

Logo no início, vou deixar a imagem com dimensão menor e padronizada. 100 x 100. Isso é pra ficar
mais leve, não é um passo obrigatório, apesar de ser recomendado.
Também vou considerar as imagens em tons de cinza e não colorida para reduzí-las ainda mais.

```
img <- imager::grayscale(img)
img <- imager::resize(img, 100, 100)
```

Agora, possuimos uma matriz 100 x 100 com cada elemento representando o tom de cinza.

Eu prefiro representar a imagem como um data.frame no R, por ser mais fácil de manipular.
Então uso o seguinte código.

```
img_df <- as.matrix(img) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(x = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  gather(y, t, -x) %>% 
  mutate(y = extract_numeric(y))
```

Aqui a imagem é representada em 3 colunas de um data.frame. As duas primeiras `x` e
`y` identificam a posição do pixel. A última representa o tom de cinza do pixel.

Para a entrada em um modelo estatístico/algoritmo de machine-learning é necessário obter uma 
base de dados em que cada linha é uma observação/um indivíduo/uma unidade amostral, e cada coluna é uma característica observada naquele indivíduo.

Então, para classificar imagens de gatos e cachorros precisamos de uma base de dados em que cada imagem está representada em uma linha e cada pixel da imagem seja uma coluna (os pixels são as informações observadas da imagem). Além disso precisaremos de uma coluna indicando se a imagem é
de um gato ou de um cachorro para treinar o algoritmo/ estimar os seus parâmetros.

Para transformar a imagem em uma linha uso o seguinte comando:

```
img_line <- img_df %>%
  mutate(colname = sprintf("x%03dy%03d", x, y)) %>%
  select(-x, -y) %>%
  spread(colname, t)
```

Se você quisesse considerar a cor da imagem no seu modelo, nesta etapa precisaria criar uma coluna 
para cada pixel e cada cor, ou seja 3x100x100 = 30.000, você terminaria com cada imagem representada por uma linha de 30.000 colunas.

## Processando uma série de imagens.

Expliquei como você faria para processar uma imagem, mas para treinar o algoritmo são necessárias diversas imagens. Vou encapsular o código anterior em uma função e utilizá-lo para processar uma série de imagens.

```
processar <- function(path){
  img <- imager::load.image("train/cat.0.jpg")
  img <- imager::grayscale(img)
  img <- imager::resize(img, 100, 100)
  img_df <- as.matrix(img) %>% 
    data.frame() %>% 
    mutate(x = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
    gather(y, t, -x) %>% 
    mutate(y = extract_numeric(y))
  img_line <- img_df %>%
    mutate(colname = sprintf("x%03dy%03d", x, y)) %>%
    select(-x, -y) %>%
    spread(colname, t)
  return(img_line)
}
```

Para fins de demonstração, vou pegar uma amostra de 100 imagens de cachorro e de 100 imagens de gato para o treinamento do modelo. Na prática, são necessárias muito mais imagens.

```
arqs <- list.files("train", full.names = T)
amostra_gato <- arqs[str_detect(arqs, "cat")] %>% sample(100)
amostra_cachorro <- arqs[str_detect(arqs, "dog")] %>% sample(100)
amostra <- c(amostra_gato, amostra_cachorro)

bd <- plyr::ldply(amostra, processar)
Y <- as.factor(rep(c("gato", "cachorro"), each = 100) ) # vetor de respostas
```

Esse passo demora bastante e é computacionalmenter intenso. Você faz muitos processamentos e 
imagens são arquivos pesados.

## Modelagem

Aqui qualquer algoritmo de machine-learning poderia ser utilizado. Você já transformou as suas
imagens em um banco de dados convencional. Já aviso, isso geralmente demora bastante. No meu computador para treinar com 200 imagens de 10.000 colunas demorou aprox 30 min.

Vou usar random forest para fazer a classificação, mas você poderia realmente qualquer modelo.

```
m <- randomForest::randomForest(bd, Y, ntree = 100)
```

Não vou entrar em detalhes de como a modelagem deveria ser realizada. O certo é você separar 
uma base de treino e uma de teste. Verificar que não teve overfitting, fazer tuning dos parâmetros usando cross-validation, etc. Mas isso tornaria a resposta muito extensa, por isso treinei um random forest usando todos os padrões da função do R (alterando apenas o número de árvores).

Verifiquei o erro apenas na base de construção também (o que é errado estatisticamente, mas bola pra frente).

```
tabela <- table(predict(m, type = "class"), Y)
acerto <- sum(diag(tabela))/sum(tabela)
acerto
```

## Previsão para a imagem inicial

Com o modelo treinado e uma nova imagem processada, use o seguinte comando para prever a
categoria:

```
predict(m, newdata = img_line)
```

Comment: Daniel, Parabéns. Animal...

Comment: Ganhou o meu +1 pois a resposta é mesmo muito boa (apesar de eu achar a pergunta muito ampla e ter votado para fechá-la). Aliás, quando você menciona que "esse passo demora bastante e é computacionalmente intenso", tem toda a razão. Afinal, 10 mil colunas é simplesmente um absurdo! rs Apesar de servir como uma boa base para entendimento, quase nunca se usa diretamente os valores dos pixels como características. Há outras características que podem ser extraídas das imagens com algoritmos de processamento intermediário que são mais úteis em reduzir consideravelmente as dimensões do problema. :)

Comment: Concordo @LuizVieira! Não sou grande entendedor desse assunto, mas acredito que isso seja feito em alguns algoritmos (mesmo sendo absurdo). Veja esse tutorial do tensor flow https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks Claro que são imagens menores (32x32), mas são **muito** mais imagens também.

Comment: @DanielFalbel O reconhecimento de caracteres escritos a mão, por exemplo, também costuma usar imagens de exemplo bem pequenas no treinamento. Dai a dimensão do problema é bem mais reduzida, mas ainda assim 32x32 é bem grande. Mas há outros problemas em usar dados crus (raw data) como os valores dos pixels. A variância pode ser muito grande, além de que muitas das "colunas" podem ser simplesmente inúteis ou ajudar a ter [sobreajuste](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobreajuste). Por isso é importante selecionar as melhores features.

Comment: @DanielFalbel O próprio link que vc passa [tem uma seção sobre seleção de características](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/linear/overview.html#feature-columns-and-transformations) que menciona: "*Much of the work of designing a linear model consists of transforming raw data into suitable input features.*" :) Aliás, eu explico um pouco desse assunto [numa das minhas respostas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40149/73) por aqui.

Comment: @LuizVieira nesta parte ele está falando sobre modelos lineares, mas na parte das Deep CNN's ele realmente usa a raw images no algoritmo. Claro que quando você vai ver, esse algoritmo demorou 4 semanas para treinar em umcluster de não sei quantas GPU's. Mas acho que aí que está o *state of the art* dos algoritmos de reconhecimento de imagens. Para nós, mortais que não temos clusters gigantes de computadores, resta selecionar as melhores características.

Comment: @DanielFalbel Verdade. Mas independentemente de ser ou não linear, o meu ponto era mais sobre a maldição da dimensionalidade (o sistema requerer volume exponencial de dados de treinamento conforme cresce o número de características utilizadas). Mas dessa vez sou eu que não entendo muito de *deep learning*, talvez vc tenha razão. :)

Comment: Daniel, é isso mesmo, você manja mesmo do negócio kkkkkkkk. Só que eu não tenho muita experiência com Redes neurais. Eu te agradeço pela resposta e vou tentar implementar o seu cógido... gostaria de saber se posso entrar em contato direto com você pelo email ou alguma coisa assim.

Comment: @DanielFalbel há algum programa que você usa para tratar estas imagens para que o algoritmo seja treinado? Como você faz isso?