# Como detectar e ler texto em uma imagem?

Tags: processamento-de-imagens

Pretendo desenvolver uma aplicação por meio da qual uma imagem submetida pelo usuário deverá ser processada e ter seus blocos de texto detectados e lidos.

Como devo fazê-lo?

Comment: Você pode tentar usar uma api por exemplo: https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: Rodrigo bom dia. Andei dando uma estudada sobre reconhecimento de imagem, então vou deixar alguns link's que me ajudou a dar pelo menos uma base: http://biblioteca.unilasalle.edu.br/docs_online/tcc/graduacao/ciencia_da_computacao/2014/tstomasel.pdf , https://sourceforge.net/projects/jocr/ , http://forum.clubedohardware.com.br/topic/412675-algoritmo-para-reconhecimento-de-imagens/ , esse e um dos meu preferidos : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139570/reconhecimento-de-padr%C3%B5es

Comment: Você pdoe tentar adaptar o código deste projeto também: https://github.com/dfalbel/captchaReceita2

Comment: eu recomendo o opencv, já fiz trabalhos de faculdade com ele, é open source e tem muito material na net

Comment: Você vai ter que usar OCR para detectar os textos contidos na imagem, acredito que seja muito trabalhoso fazer do zero. Mas poderá usar uma API para isso, sugiro que dê uma verificada na nessa api:
[phpOCR: Recognize text & objects in graphical images](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html)

Comment: Por mais que a pergunta seja interessante estou achando ela ampla mesmo, como já votaram. A pergunta não tem uma delimitação clara do que deseja. Acho que uma edição pode recuperá-la, na forma atual, conforme já mostram os comentários, é difícil dar uma resposta adequada.